# Update This Extension to Handle FlatLoopValueInjection

Tags: c#, generics, valueinjecter

I found this code on stackoverflow but I noticed it can't handle FlatLoopValueInjection and I would like to make it handle this but I can't figure out how.

```
public static ICollection<TTo> InjectFrom<TFrom, TTo>(this ICollection<TTo> to, IEnumerable<TFrom> from) where TTo : new()
        {
            foreach (var source in from)
            {
                var target = new TTo();
                target.InjectFrom(source);
                to.Add(target);
            }
            return to;
        }
```

I know it this needs to be updated  `target.InjectFrom(source);`but I am not sure with what as it would be good if it could take anything in(FlatLoopValueInjection, UnflatLoopValueInjection and etc) and use it

Comment: That is not what I wanted Omu. Adding InjectFrom<FlatLoopValueInjection> just makes it hard coded to use that. I wanted it to be still generic but handle (FlatLoopValueInjection, UnflatLoopValueInjection and etc)

Comment: FlatLoopValueInjection does the same as InjectFrom + flattenning